# Check Umbraco site is ready and it's connected to the database

Tags: c#, umbraco, recurring

My Umbraco site has a recurring task which runs every 60 mins. The problem is when Umbraco is not installed yet, the task block the installation process.

I'm trying to detect the status of my Umbraco site by this:

```
var isApplicationInstalled = uQuery.RootNodeId != -1;
if (isApplicationInstalled)
{
    // run the task
}
```

But `uQuery.RootNodeId` seems to always return `-1` and the task has never run.
How to detect that Umbraco site is installed and it's connected to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to check the Umbraco application's status via [ApplicationContext](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.html):

`ApplicationContext.Current.IsConfigured` check Umbraco is configured.
`ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.CanConnect` check Umbraco can connect to the database.

So the code will be:

```
    var isApplicationInstalled = ApplicationContext.Current.IsConfigured &&
                                    ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.CanConnect;
    if (isApplicationInstalled)
    {
        // run the task
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution: Override **ApplicationStarted** method in **ApplicationEventHandler**.

The method is called when all required bootups is ready. Then you can override it, set a global setting to true (maybe you can define a global setting like UmbracoIsReady). And in your recurring task, you just need to retrieve UmbracoIsReady to check.

```
public class StartupHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication,
        ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        base.ApplicationStarted(umbracoApplication, applicationContext);

        //Set a global variable/information to make sure that the Umbraco is ready
        Setting.UmbracoIsReady = true;
    }
}
```